NPY exchange between numpy 1.x and 2.x
Is there a way to read NPY files, saved with numpy 1.x in numpy 2.x ?
The attempt to read old NPY files with np.load() results in "ModuleNotFoundError".
As I understand, the reason is changed structure of numpy modules. Is there a way to overcome this?

Can you give more details? I can save a .npy file in numpy 1.26.4 and load it in 2.0.2 with no issues. Are you sure you have numpy installed in your environment?

People have been using v2 for a couple of months, and I haven't seen any other issues with numpy save/load. What module is the problem?  What is in the file?  Straightforward numpy numeric  arrays, or some object, non-numpy elements (pickled)?
